# How to correctly use next() of tinyxml in QT? My project can be debugged but not released

Tags: qt, tinyxml

I am using the tinyxml library to make a QT interface project. The problem now is that it can only be debugged and cannot be released. According to my positioning, there should be a problem with the “Next()” method in TiXmlAttribute. When I use this function, it will appear seg error. And it can be run without using it.Is there any solution, because I have to use this function.

```
    TiXmlAttribute *pAttr;
    pAttr = pEle->FirstAttribute();// the first attribute
    while(nullptr != pAttr){
        pAttr = pAttr->Next();
    }
```

Comment: There is no error when only using  code " TiXmlAttribute *pAttr ";

Comment: Can we see the definition and initialization of pEle? I'm also curious as to whether you get the segmentation fault on the first call to Next(), or on subsequent calls.

Comment: solve(TiXmlNode *pNode),  pEle = pNode->ToElement();